# wagtail - page for showing categories; how?

Tags: django, wagtail

I wouldl like to implement categories page using wagtail but it is quite difficult to understand for a novice programmer. When just following the tutorial of wagtail(getting started), the categories field is implemented in their official tutorial but I don't know how to get an access

For instance, in Django, If I define two models like Categories, and Posts, I can access articles that fall under a specific category using Foreign key
and making a view using something like Category.posts_set.all()

But how can I do it in wagtail?
Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list all categories from e.g. a Category Index Page, then you'll need to get all categories and add them to the context. Assuming your model structure is the same as in the tutorial at https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html#categories, then you can do

```py
class CategoryIndexPage(Page):
    
    # ... other fields go here

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context["categories"] = BlogCategory.objects.all()
        return context
```

Then in your template:

```
    {% if categories %}
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for category in categories %}
                <li style="display: inline">
                    {% image category.icon fill-32x32 style="vertical-align: middle" %}
                    {{ category.name }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you so much! but I would like blog articles to be rendered following each of the category. I figured that tag = request.GET.get('tag')
        blogpages = BlogPage.objects.filter(tags__name=tag)

Comment: wagtail's another tutorial's snippet  "tag = request.GET.get('tag')
        blogpages = BlogPage.objects.filter(tags__name=tag)" would help, but I can't get request.GET.get('tag') since in the tutorial model 'tag' isn't really defined. Maybe I should look at wagtail source code for cateogories?

Comment: Tag is a built-in model in Wagtail, see the way the BlogPage has a `tags` field at https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html?highlight=tags#categories. `request.GET.get('tag')` is a Django concept that Wagtail uses. You'd have to visit a page URL with a tag querystring, e.g. www.example.com/mypage?tag=foo.

Comment: I don't want to implement tag query but category(and I mentioned tag thinking it might be similar to category queryset) I still don't know how to get queryset and display it under each and every category